# Divi Builder not loading saved layout

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with Divi Builder. I am using Pagely to clone one site into a staging environment. The cloning part goes well and everything is in place.

When I try to access a page on the staging in order to edit it (Via Divi builder) the structure is not there. If I go back to the public are I can see the page structure in place and also I can confirm that the data is there because I checked using inspect that the poststuff text area contains the same data.

It seems that on the staging the structure under et_pb_main_container is not loaded properly[image: Staging]

Instead if I check the live site the structure looks like this:
[image: Live]

Finally the frontend displays:
[image]

Instead of what I am able to see on the live site:
[image]

Comment: I have this problem in Divi. It is a problem in Divi. Update your theme. I do not have this problem in newest version of Divi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the layout to the library? I would give that a shot then load it and see if that jogs the content.

Comment: loading anything from the library does indeed load my content with it, but I always have to delete the extra added elements. This is not something i can use long term sadly. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to do that every time you load the page or just the first time? If it's every time the only other recommendations I would have is try updating your theme, if you're already at the latest version try rolling back and see if that helps. Lastly, this is the nuclear option, try manually remigrating your site. I have had bad luck in the past with migration tools but manual migrations usually work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable all plugins and then check or try to use the updated version of Divi Theme.